# Templates instantiation confusion

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

This is my code to check whether class has member function `begin` or not :

```
template<typename T> struct has_begin
{
    struct dummy {typedef void const_iterator;};
    typedef typename std::conditional< has_iterator<T>::yes, T, dummy>::type TType;
    typedef typename TType::const_iterator Iter;
    struct fallBack{ Iter begin() const ; Iter end() const;};
    struct checker : T, fallBack {};
    template <typename B, B> struct cht;
    template<typename C> static char check(cht< Iter (fallBack::*)() const, &C::begin>*); // problem is here
    template<typename C> static char (&check(...))[2];
public:
    enum {no = (sizeof(check<checker>(0))==sizeof(char)),
     yes=!no};
};
```

If I change second argument of `cht` in `check(cht< Iter (fallBack::*)() const, &C::begin>*);` to 
`&checker::begin` , This doesn't changes the semantic of code since `cht`'s second template argument is always `checker` due to this `enum {no = (sizeof(check<checker>(0))==sizeof(char))`

but code change results in [error](http://www.ideone.com/zJzBV) now which are :

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of 'has_begin<std::vector<int> >':
prog.cpp:31:51:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:23:38: error: reference to 'has_begin<std::vector<int> >::checker::begin' is ambiguous
```

I want to know what is the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: Your struct is very complex. What is it supposed to do? Looks like a check if the class T has a member function named begin

Comment: @VJovic You're right , I edited the Q's first line :)

Comment: What error do you get if you make the change?

Comment: @AlanStokes Ambiguous call error :(

Comment: @Freak Enum: `What error do you get` means `Please post the error message you get verbatim (copy+paste)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the Wikipedia article about SFINAE - Substitution Failure is Not An Error:

> [...] when creating a candidate set for overload resolution, some (or all)
>   candidates of that set may be the result of substituting deduced
>   template arguments for the template parameters. If an error occurs
>   during substitution, the compiler removes the potential overload from
>   the candidate set instead of stopping with a compilation error [...]

In your code as posted, an ambiguity error occurs while instantiating the function template `check` with parameter `C` == `typename has_begin<T>::checker`, and that substitution leads to the error, so the instantiation is simply removed from the overload set.

If you change your code, a similar ambiguaty error occurs with `&checker::begin`.
This time, however, it is not the result of substituting the template parameter C for the `check` function template. The subsitution of the template parameter T of `struct has_begin` is not relevant for the SFINAE rule, as that template has already been successfully instantiated.

Comment: your first para isn't making sense to me . Can you explain the reason more clearly?